# ‘sign’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “OAuth” while using twitteR for R

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to scrape tweets on a specific search string using R library twitteR.
I am able to authenticate fine, but whenever I try to use functions like

```
 'searchTwitter()' or 'getUser()',
```

I keep getting an error as below

> " Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : 
>     ‘sign’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “OAuth” "

I am new to R and twitter, so could someone please explain how to resolve this?

My code is:

```
load("twitterAuth")
use_oauth_token(cred)
search_string <- "nba"
no_of_tweets <- 100
tweets<-searchTwitteR("srk")
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I use `twitteR` is

```
# Credentials
api_key <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
api_secret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token_secret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = api_key, 
                    consumer_secret = api_secret, 
                    access_token = access_token, 
                    access_secret = access_token_secret)

tdy <- as.Date("2017-02-11")
mnth <- as.character(seq(from = as.Date("2013-01-31"), to = tdy, by = "month"))
mnth <- c(mnth, as.character(tdy))

for (i in 1:length(mnth) - 1) {
  tmp <- NULL
  i <- 1

  while (any(class(tmp) %in% "error") | is.null(tmp)) {
    tmp <- tryCatch(searchTwitter("#nba", n = 2400, since = "2013-01-31", until = "2013-02-28"), 
                    error = function(e) e,
                    warning = function(w) w)
    save(tmp, file = paste(mnth[i], "___", mnth[i+1], ".RData", sep = ""))
  }

  Sys.sleep(1200)
}
```

This works for smallish datasets. If you're trying to do some heavy duty scraping, it will probably be best to save things in a database.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turns out my approach was wrong with the authentication. Now its working fine.

Comment: @PratikPatra Please post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I messed up the authentication part. Here's my solution:

library("twitteR")

library("ROAuth")

library("RCurl")

library("httr")

## Contains the access id for the Twitter App used for accessing twitter

access_id<-"XXXXXXXXX"

## Contains the access secret for the Twitter App used for accessing twitter

access_secret<-"XXXXXXX"

## Contains the token id for the Twitter App used for accessing twitter(used for direct authentication without browser)

token_id<-"XXXXXX"

## Contains the token secret for the Twitter App used for accessing twitter(used for direct authentication without browser)

token_secret<-"XXXXXXX"

## Sets up the twitter session for crawling tweets

setup_twitter_oauth(access_id,access_secret,token_id,token_secret)

## The searchstr contains the search keyword

searchstr="Johnson's Baby"

## tweets is an object of 'status' type specified by twitteR API

tweets <- searchTwitter(searchString = searchstr, n=500,lang = 'en')